# Apache2 ignoring wildcard vhosts when using IP vhosts

Tags: apache2, vhosts

I have several vhosts on an apache2 server. They are accessible both from internet (external interface) and intranet (internal interface).
Now, for one vhost, I would like to serve a different content if comming from internet rather than from intranet.

I have had configurations like this for my vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName site1.example.com
        ProxyPass / <ip_1>:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / <ip_1>:443/
...

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName site2.example.com
        ProxyPass / <ip_2>:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / <ip_2>:443/
...
```

Now, I would like one vhost (here site1.example.com) to serve (proxypass) a different server when accessing from intranet, so I modified its configuration :

```
<VirtualHost <ip_3>:443>
        ServerName site1.example.com
        ProxyPass / <ip_3>:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / <ip_3>:443/
...

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName site1.example.com
        ProxyPass / <ip_1>:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / <ip_1>:443/
...

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName site2.example.com
        ProxyPass / <ip_2>:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / <ip_2>:443/
...
```

This configuration allows me to access `<ip_3>:443/` when comming from intranet (IP match first entry), and `<ip_1>:443/` when comming from internet.

The problem is, when accessing all other vhosts from intranet, they are all redirected to `<ip_3>:443/` (IP based vhost), while their name does not match the ServerName, and there is a vhost with wildcard IP (`*:443`) matching the name.

If I understand, apache finds an IP match with the vhost `<ip_3>:443`, and it just ignores all the wildcard vhosts (`*:443`). Therefore, its "best" match is `<ip_3>:443` vhost.

Is there a way to have it work, without having to define an IP-based configuration for all other vhosts (there are many of them) ?

Comment: you will always get locked into the best matching interface if there is a specific match.  I would use <if> to make the proxypass conditional on the local IP.